# How to Request Location permission before showing map set up in Xaml. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-permissions

I recently updated sdk level to 6.0 in Xamarin.forms.
I used Xaml to place a map on a page. Since I updated to 6.0 permission is required to show the map. My problem now is I can't figure out how to request permission to show the map before the app attempts to show it. As a result I get an unhandled exception.

```
 public MapPage()
        {
            Init();
            InitializeComponent();


            azureService = AzureService.defaultManager;

        }
        private async Task Init()
        {
            await RequestLocationPermission();
        }
        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            MyMap.MoveToRegion(
               MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                   new Position(0, 0),
                   Distance.FromMiles(10.0)));

        }

private async Task RequestLocationPermission()
        {
            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                    }

                    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
                    status = results[Permission.Location];
                }

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                                        }
                else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

If the map is set up in Xaml, how can I request permission before showing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your constructor is set up right now, you are starting the permission request in a task which will run in a separate thread. That means that InitializeComponent() will probably run before the user can grant permission. The problem is you can't make the constructor an async method so there isn't an easy way to get around this.

To make this work without to much effort, you can move the InitializeComponent() from your constructor into your "if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)" block. It would probably look something like this:

```
if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
     {
         InitializeComponent()
     });
}
```

With this approach you will have to be careful what you do in OnAppearing() as it will probably be called before InitializeComponent(). If you try to access any of your UI components at that point it will fail.

However I think the better way to handle this is to move your permission request code one level up. In other words put it in the class where you are instantiating this page from. Then you can show this page if access is granted, or another page that does not have the map if access is denied. It would make for a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably end up having to create the map in C#. Or else I would have to request permission in App.cs. The map page is on a tabbed page which is the main page. So it is not like I could pass through to something else if permission is denied.

Comment: Hey. I finally got to try this solution and I cannot get it to work. The permission plugin isn't working. I posted A question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473975/xamarin-forms-android-permission-prompt-not-displaying) can you help with that?

Comment: @xerotolerant If you didn't make the proposed solution didn't solve your issue, then this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: I marked it right because it seems like a reasonable solution to the problem of getting permission for something before it is rendered in xaml. His answer is basically request permission before initializeconponent.

Comment: Ok after getting the permission plugin to work correctly I ended up asking for permission for the map before Initialize component is run and it worked.