# Xamarin.forms android permission prompt not displaying

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the [permission plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) by James Montemagno.

I basically copied the example however the permission is unknown after the line to request it. No dialog even shows.

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }
            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000);
                //LabelGeolocation.Text = "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Location permission: {0}", status);
```

I have the Permissions in my android manifest. This problem only started showing once I updated my target platform to 6.0+

I also added this to my MainActivity

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

This question is different since it has nothing to do with maps. I cannot use any real time permission since the prompts are simply not showing within the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Request Location permission before showing map set up in Xaml. Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325729/how-to-request-location-permission-before-showing-map-set-up-in-xaml-xamarin-fo)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate since I am asking why requesting permission using the plugin isn't working. There is no mention of xaml of maps. The request for Location permission is failing outright regardless of what I want it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some how MainApplication.cs was not installed along with the plugin. It was put in the correct directory but I had to manually add it to the project. Not really sure why that occurred but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `MainApplication.cs` is not added in my Android Project. The better way that i used is to uninstall the `CurrentActivity Plugin` along with all the `NUgets` that depend on it. I again install `CurrentActivity Plugin` and all other plugins. Now the `MainApplication.cs` is in the root directory of the Android project.